# Xcode: Cannot set optimization level for debug

Tags: ios, xcode, optimization

I can't add it and there's no debug optimization, yet I got the log:

*ProjectName was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.*

[image]

More info: I went to the edit build scheme and it's set as debug mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you've accidentally deleted your debug configuration. To prove this to yourself, look at your project's Info pane. You should see this — but I'm betting you won't:

[image]

A configuration is just a name, so you can easily recreate the debug configuration right here in the project settings; but that won't magically restore all the corresponding default build setting values. Your best bet is to consider this project hosed: make a new project, to get the template's values for the build settings, and migrate everything from this project into it.

Comment: Alternatively, if you've been diligently using a version control system like git, it may be easier to just revert your .pbxproj.

Comment: Well looked into the git, it happened when a co-worker deleted the Cocoapods workspace. Thank you very much.
Restored everything it worked perfectly! Thank you very much!

Comment: @robmayoff and matt can you look inti this problem of mine please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45078851/optimization-stepping-may-behave-oddly-ios-unity